# Why section header always showing in grey colour and in one line? in Swift

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, sections

I am using two tableviews side by side, so need section header text in two lines and in black colour. but its not coming like that.. why?

**code:** I have used these methods but still not showing header text in black colour and in two lines... please let me know, **how to show header text in black and in two lines**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> CGFloat {
    35
 }

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.textColor = UIColor.black
    (view as! UITableViewHeaderFooterView).textLabel?.numberOfLines = 2

}

func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        return nonProSubategory.count
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        return proSubategory.count
    }
    return 0
}
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        return nonProSubategory[section].title
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        return proSubategory[section].title
    }
    return ""
}
```

o/p: with this code text always showing in grey colour and in one line.. here "beauty,health.." and "home services" are header text

[Screen of header colour in grey and one line](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JVmF3.png)

**EDIT:**

if i use only these two methods:

```
 func numberOfSections(in tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        return nonProSubategory.count
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        return proSubategory.count
    }
    return 0
}
private func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {

    let v = UILabel()
    v.textColor = .black
    v.numberOfLines = 2

    // you can set a font here, if desired
    //  for example:
    //v.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15)

    if tableView == tableView1 {
        v.text = nonProSubategory[section].title
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        v.text = proSubategory[section].title
    }
    return v
}
```

o/p: here header title("beauty,health.." and "home services") is missing..

[edit code o/p](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0vqPm.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You *could* take your approach... however...

First, you should always properly cast classes and unwrap optionals:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplayHeaderView view: UIView, forSection section: Int) {
    if let v = view as? UITableViewHeaderFooterView,
       let label = v.textLabel
    {
        label.textColor = .black
        label.numberOfLines = 2
    }
}
```

The default `.textLabel` has been deprecated though, plus I don't think `.numberOfLines` is going to work.

Much better approach is to return your own view for the section header.

This example uses a `UILabel` as the view to return, but you can return a more complex view with various subviews, if you wanted to:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    
    let v = UILabel()
    v.textColor = .black
    v.numberOfLines = 2
    
    // you can set a font here, if desired
    //  for example:
    //v.font = .italicSystemFont(ofSize: 15)
    
    if tableView == tableView1 {
        v.text = nonProSubategory[section].title
    } else if tableView == tableView2 {
        v.text = proSubategory[section].title
    }
    return v
}
```

Then get rid of `titleForHeaderInSection`, `willDisplayHeaderView` and `heightForHeaderInSection` (height will be handle be auto-layout).

Comment: I am using `viewForHeaderInSection` now.... and deleted `titleForHeaderInSection, willDisplayHeaderView and heightForHeaderInSection`....... but now i am not getting total  header in tableview.... did i miss anything in storyboard? should i add anything ?... i know ur code is correct... but why am not getting header

Comment: @SwiftiOS - what do you mean by: *"not getting total header in tableview"*?

Comment: I have edited my post with my recent code with o/p screen shot..did i miss anything in storybord?.. bcz ur code is correct

Comment: @SwiftiOS - are you sure that is being called? Using `private` shouldn't even allow the code to compile...

Comment: I got `Instance method 'tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)' nearly matches optional requirement 'tableView(_:titleForHeaderInSection:)' of protocol 'UITableViewDataSource'` `Make 'tableView(_:viewForHeaderInSection:)' private to silence this warning`

Comment: so i added private... if private or not in both conditions `viewForHeaderInSection ` is not calling... why?

Comment: @SwiftiOS - sounds like your class doesn't conform to `UITableViewDelegate`? Make sure you have `class SomeViewCOntroller: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {` and set the Delegate of your tableView(s).